# How remote to jboss 7 eap with jcosole or jmc

Tags: java, jboss, jconsole

I want to remote to jboss 7 eap with jconsole or jmc, but it is not working.
I want remote to jboss to check the performance of jboss.

Comment: What have you tried? How did they not work?

Comment: I use jconsole and then in put service:jmx:remote+http://[server_ip]:[Port]
It will show error connection not success.

Comment: Hello all,
Have anyone can help me?

Comment: Edit your post to include the error message, and what you found in your research about the error message, what you tried to fix the error message, etc.

Comment: Do you have social media?
I want to send an error screen to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not experienced with the tools you're using. I think you'll have the best luck by copying the error message and pasting it in your question. Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions can be answered quickly and as clear as possible. Don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: @MotChantha Asking for people's social media etc, that is not how Stack Overflow works. Stack Overflow is not your support platform, it is a Question & Answer site. Include all relevant information in the question itself. You can do so by clicking the `edit` link underneath your question.